# Is it possible to load one particular file from localhost?

Tags: javascript, linux, browser

In my application statics files are loading from proxy server I want to load one JS file from my localhost so that I can edit and test it with my production app.

For example:- 
www.staticserver.com/39349/file.js

localhost/xyz/file.js

can I do it in /etc/hosts file or any browser plug-in ?

Answer (score 0):

To do this do you need a local http server running in your machine test :-)

Search and install Wamp Server if are trying to do this in windows, if are in linux, install Apache server

Comment: I have apache running locally but I am not able to get that particular  file loading from localhost.

Comment: All my static files are getting downloaded from proxy server suppose I have 3 js files test1.js test2.js and test3.js I want to load test1.js from my localhost and all other files from my remote server, because there are so many files on remort server and comming from diffrent-diffrent servers through proxy.

Comment: to edit you are required to find the path where these files are on the server and just open with one editor, to see it in the browser may depend on the configuration of your apache, you can try http://serverIP/folder/file.js or http://localhost/folder/file.js